# Why does the TGV Train stop at the end of Mission Impossible?

Tags: plot-explanation, mission-impossible, mission-impossible-1996

At the end of *Mission Impossible* (1996) the TGV train goes into the tunnel and the helicopter follows. When a driver/pilot of the train sees the helicopter following them, he informs the main driver to not stop the train since the helicopter might crash into the train.

Later Ethan Hunt puts the explosive gum on the helicopter and it crashes, the train stops and the blade of the helicopter almost reaches the throat of Ethan Hunt. Why does the train stop?

Comment: Downvoters, atleast comment how I should improve my question!

Answer (score 1):

The train conductor in the back initially sees the helicopter chasing the train and tells the conductor in the front not to stop the train.

Once the helicopter crashes and explodes, the conductor in the back must have seen that (and also felt the helicopter drag on the tracks and slow down the train), so he tells the conductor at the front to stop the train - or applies the emergency brakes himself.

[image]

Comment: When the helicopter crashed, it was no longer connected to the train right? Phelps had removed it. So, there is no question of helicopter slowing down the train. Also, if the driver sees the helicopter crash, he would urge the main driver to speed up the train so that crashed helicopter doesn't come in contact with train. Why would he ask to stop the train?

Comment: @NagabhushanSN When the helicopter is flying through the air on its own, the train has to maintain its speed or the helicopter may hit it. Once the helicopter explodes, it is still connected to the train. [There are several shots of it being dragged along the tracks.](https://youtu.be/Cho039BrHpg?t=86) The dead helicopter is pulling backwards on the train, dragging along the tracks, so the train can reduce speed and stop without the risk of the helicopter hitting it.

Comment: pardon me but I don't see the helicopter connected to the train when it explodes. Also think this way. If the helicopter was still connected to the train, when would Jim jump onto helicopter from train? He would first try to disconnect them and then jump onto Helicopter right?